# How to wrap the first 10 commas with double quotes?

Tags: bash, csv, sed

Here is my input.csv file

```
dealerid,address,city,state,zip,vin,stocknumber,type,color,year,make,model,trim,bodystyle,fueltype,mileage,transmission,interiorcolor,interiorfabric,price,titlestatus,warranty,options_text,cylinders,engine,engineaspiration,enginetext,drivetrain,transmissiontext,mpgcity,mpghighway,features_text,vdc_url,images
TS06095298,999 wanna Road,Windsor,CT,06095,22HDT13S922218113,298,Used,Red,2002,OLDSMOBILE,BRAVADA,,,,136000,AUTOMATIC,,,2200,Clear,Available,"This vehicle is offered for sale by a verified private seller and features: FREE vehicle history & title report. Original window sticker available. Seller`s identity, email and phone verified. Secure cashless transactions. No cash needed. Pay securely by debit card or ACH. Bill of Sale and receipt issued for completed transactions. Vehicle financing options may be available.",,,,,,,,,,https://www.example.com/listings/298,"https://www.example.com/rails/00008.jpg,https://www.example.com/rails/AM00010.jpg"
TS06095298,999 wanna Road,Windsor,CT,06095,22HDT13S922123453,307,Used,Brown,2008,HONDA,599,,,,217538,AUTOMATIC,,,3500,Clear,Available,"This vehicle is offered for sale by a verified private seller and features: FREE vehicle history & title report. Original window sticker available. Seller`s identity, email and phone verified. Secure cashless transactions. No cash needed. Pay securely by debit card or ACH. Bill of Sale and receipt issued for completed transactions. Vehicle financing options may be available.",,,,,,,,,,https://www.example.com/listings/211,"https://www.example.com/rails/00008.jpg,https://www.example.com/rails/AM00010.jpg"
```

I need to wrap all columns with double quotes so I end up with a file like so:

```
"dealerid","address","city","state","zip","vin","stocknumber","type","color","year","make","model","trim","bodystyle","fueltype","mileage","transmission","interiorcolor","interiorfabric","price","titlestatus","warranty","options_text","cylinders","engine","engineaspiration","enginetext","drivetrain","transmissiontext","mpgcity","mpghighway","features_text","vdc_url","images"
"TS06095298","999 wanna Road,Windsor","CT","06095","22HDT13S922218113","298","Used","Red","2002","OLDSMOBILE","BRAVADA","","","","136000,AUTOMATIC","","","2200","Clear","Available","This vehicle is offered for sale by a verified private seller and features: FREE vehicle history & title report. Original window sticker available. Seller`s identity, email and phone verified. Secure cashless transactions. No cash needed. Pay securely by debit card or ACH. Bill of Sale and receipt issued for completed transactions. Vehicle financing options may be available.","","","","","","","","","","https://www.example.com/listings/298","https://www.example.com/rails/00008.jpg,https://www.example.com/rails/AM00010.jpg"
"TS06095298","999 wanna Road,Windsor","CT","06095","22HDT13S922123453","307","Used","Brown","2008","HONDA","599","","","","217538","AUTOMATIC","","","3500","Clear","Available","This vehicle is offered for sale by a verified private seller and features: FREE vehicle history & title report. Original window sticker available. Seller`s identity, email and phone verified. Secure cashless transactions. No cash needed. Pay securely by debit card or ACH. Bill of Sale and receipt issued for completed transactions. Vehicle financing options may be available.","","","","","","","","","","https://www.example.com/listings/211","https://www.example.com/rails/00008.jpg,https://www.example.com/rails/AM00010.jpg"
```

The file is pretty constant throughout with the same missing data from certain columns.

The images column and the features text column come wrapped already.

Seeing the same info was missing throughout I decided to add double quotes to the beginning of each line and started to replace the commas with double quotes but started running into some issues.

Here is what I have so far. I know the code is not very efficient but it's a start.

```
#!/bin/bash

#- Temp Directories
tmp_dir="$(mktemp -d -t 'csv.XXXXX' || mktemp -d 2>/dev/null)"
tmp_input1="${tmp_dir}/temp_input1.csv"
tmp_input2="${tmp_dir}/temp_input2.csv"
tmp_input3="${tmp_dir}/temp_input3.csv"

#- Variables
client="00000"
wDir="$(pwd)"
ftpDir="${wDir}/.clientftp"
clientDir="${ftpDir}/${client}"
csvFile="${clientDir}/final.csv"
inputCsv="${wDir}/input.csv"

#  Lets Begin
cd "$wDir" || exit

      cp "$inputCsv" "$tmp_input1"
      dos2unix "$tmp_input1"

      #  place first line to a temp file , surrounding commas with double quotes , adding double quotes to the front and end of line
      head -1 "$tmp_input1" | sed -e 's/,/","/g;s/.*/"&"/' > "$tmp_input2"

      #  place remainding lines to a temp file
      sed 1,1d "$tmp_input1" | sed "s/^/\"/" > "$tmp_input3"
      sed -i 's/",,,,,,,,,,https/","","","","","","","","","","https/g' "$tmp_input3"
      sed -i 's/,Clear,Available,"/","Clear","Available","/g' "$tmp_input3"
      sed -i 's/,,,,/","","","","/g' "$tmp_input3"
      sed -i 's/,,,/","","","/g' "$tmp_input3"

      #  Create final file
      cat "$tmp_input2" > "$csvFile"
      cat "$tmp_input3" >> "$csvFile"

      rm -rf "$tmp_dir"

      { clear; echo ""; echo "";  echo "nano $csvFile"; echo ""; }

nano "$csvFile"
```

This script produces:

```
"dealerid","address","city","state","zip","vin","stocknumber","type","color","year","make","model","trim","bodystyle","fueltype","mileage","transmission","interiorcolor","interiorfabric","price","titlestatus","warranty","options_text","cylinders","engine","engineaspiration","enginetext","drivetrain","transmissiontext","mpgcity","mpghighway","features_text","vdc_url","images"
"TS06095298,999 wanna Road,Windsor,CT,06095,22HDT13S922218113,298,Used,Red,2002,OLDSMOBILE,BRAVADA","","","","136000,AUTOMATIC","","","2200","Clear","Available","This vehicle is offered for sale by a verified private seller and features: FREE vehicle history & title report. Original window sticker available. Seller`s identity, email and phone verified. Secure cashless transactions. No cash needed. Pay securely by debit card or ACH. Bill of Sale and receipt issued for completed transactions. Vehicle financing options may be available.","","","","","","","","","","https://www.example.com/listings/298,"https://www.example.com/rails/00008.jpg,https://www.example.com/rails/AM00010.jpg"
"TS06095298,999 wanna Road,Windsor,CT,06095,22HDT13S922123453,307,Used,Brown,2008,HONDA,599","","","","217538,AUTOMATIC","","","3500","Clear","Available","This vehicle is offered for sale by a verified private seller and features: FREE vehicle history & title report. Original window sticker available. Seller`s identity, email and phone verified. Secure cashless transactions. No cash needed. Pay securely by debit card or ACH. Bill of Sale and receipt issued for completed transactions. Vehicle financing options may be available.","","","","","","","","","","https://www.example.com/listings/211,"https://www.example.com/rails/00008.jpg,https://www.example.com/rails/AM00010.jpg"
```

So now I have a few issues:
1- The vdc_url column does not have a closing double quote
2- first 10 commas need to be wrapped with double quotes

The last column can contain more than 3 images

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your expected output has `"136000,AUTOMATIC"` on the second line, but it should be `"136000","AUTOMATIC"`, right?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes sir, all columns should be wrapped with double quotes. Good catch!

Comment: Also, `"999 wanna Road,Windsor"` should be `"999 wanna Road","Windsor"`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. You are correct. Have a look at Glenn's answer. It seemed to do the trick and it is very efficient. Thanks for the help regardless, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like ruby for quick CVS conversions:

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
    out = CSV.instance($stdout, {force_quotes: true})
    CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) {|row| out << row}
' input.csv
```

make sure you don't have any trailing whitespace on any line.

[csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) would also be a good solution.

Comment: Now that is about the coolest 4 lines off code or what ... right on Glenn!

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' -v OFS=',' '
    { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$i); $i="\"" $i "\""} }
1' file
"dealerid","address","city","state","zip","vin","stocknumber","type","color","year","make","model","trim","bodystyle","fueltype","mileage","transmission","interiorcolor","interiorfabric","price","titlestatus","warranty","options_text","cylinders","engine","engineaspiration","enginetext","drivetrain","transmissiontext","mpgcity","mpghighway","features_text","vdc_url","images"
"TS06095298","999 wanna Road","Windsor","CT","06095","22HDT13S922218113","298","Used","Red","2002","OLDSMOBILE","BRAVADA","","","","136000","AUTOMATIC","","","2200","Clear","Available","This vehicle is offered for sale by a verified private seller and features: FREE vehicle history & title report. Original window sticker available. Seller`s identity, email and phone verified. Secure cashless transactions. No cash needed. Pay securely by debit card or ACH. Bill of Sale and receipt issued for completed transactions. Vehicle financing options may be available.","","","","","","","","","","https://www.example.com/listings/298","https://www.example.com/rails/00008.jpg,https://www.example.com/rails/AM00010.jpg"
"TS06095298","999 wanna Road","Windsor","CT","06095","22HDT13S922123453","307","Used","Brown","2008","HONDA","599","","","","217538","AUTOMATIC","","","3500","Clear","Available","This vehicle is offered for sale by a verified private seller and features: FREE vehicle history & title report. Original window sticker available. Seller`s identity, email and phone verified. Secure cashless transactions. No cash needed. Pay securely by debit card or ACH. Bill of Sale and receipt issued for completed transactions. Vehicle financing options may be available.","","","","","","","","","","https://www.example.com/listings/211","https://www.example.com/rails/00008.jpg,https://www.example.com/rails/AM00010.jpg"
```